# How can I replace the same name of a file using regex but in another format?

Tags: c#, regex, file, save, file-format

I am new in programming and not so good about regex. I wish to load / read a csv File and then save in a txt File using the same name of csv File. I will give an example.

```
D:\Project\File\xxx.csv
```

After I load this file, I want to get the name "xxx" and save it in a txt file:

```
D:\Project\File\xxx.txt
```

Or maybe in another folder, for example:

```
D:\Project\Specifications\PersonInfo.csv
```

save to

```
D:\Project\DataBank\PersonInfo.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished in many ways.

Maybe what you're lacking is knowledge of the `System.IO.Path` class ([MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx)).

For instance changing the extension could be accomplished like so:

```
string originalFilePath = @"D:\Project\File\xxx.csv";
string newFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(originalFilePath, ".txt");
```

**Note**: You need to explicitate the leading dot (".") for the extension.

Here's some "Path algebra" fun you could combine to create your desired effects:

```
string originalFilePath = @"D:\Project\File\xxx.csv";
string thePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(originalFilePath);
// will be @"D:\Project\File"

string filename = Path.GetFileName(originalFilePath);
// will be "xxx.csv"

string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFilePath);
// will be "xxx"

string recombinedFilePath = Path.Combine( @"D:\OtherFolder", "somethingElse.txt" );
// will be @"D:\OtherFolder\somethingElse.txt"
```

**Note**: `Path.Combine` knows how to handle extra/missing leading/trailing backslashes.

For example:

- `Path.Combine(@"D:\MyFolder1", @"MyFolder2\MyFile.txt")`
- `Path.Combine(@"D:\MyFolder1\", @"MyFolder2\MyFile.txt")`
- `Path.Combine(@"D:\MyFolder1", @"\MyFolder2\MyFile.txt")`
- `Path.Combine(@"D:\MyFolder1\", @"\MyFolder2\MyFile.txt")`

will all yield the same result: `@"D:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2\MyFile.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need regex for that, because .NET provides a [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for dealing specifically with file name manipulations.

For example, to replace `.csv` with `.txt` you can use this call:

```
var csvPath = @"D:\Project\File\xxx.csv";
var txtPath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(csvPath)
,   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(csvPath)+".txt"
);
```

You use a similar trick to replace other parts of the file path. Here is how you change the name of the top directory:

```
var csvPath = @"D:\Project\Specifications\xxx.csv";
var txtPath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(csvPath))
,   "DataBank"
,   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(csvPath)+".txt"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex.

You can use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("D:\Project\Specifications\PersonInfo.csv");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex for this, this regex will get the part you want:

```
([^\\]+)\.[^.\\]+$
```

The first group (in the parentheses) matches one or more characters (as many as possible) which is not a backslash. Then there need to be a literal dot. Then one or more characters (as many as possible) that are not a dot or backslash, then the end of the string. The group captures the wanted part.